# How to use multiple "Quick Create" forms per entity

Tags: dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-2013

CRM 2013 allows a customiser to add multiple "Quick Create" forms against an entity. In the case of our ISV product, this is potentially useful since we always avoid customising "native" forms in favour of creating our own form.

However given that:

- Quick Forms cannot be deactivated
- Quick Forms cannot have security roles defined against them
- There is no mechanism as a user to select or change which Quick Create form to use
- There is no mechanism to set a preferred Quick Create form

What is the point of *multiple* Quick Create forms?

My goal was to create a custom Quick Create form against the Account entity to avoid changing the native Account Quick Create form but there is seemingly no way to allow my users to use this form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typical - Despite earlier research, I found the answer within minutes of posting the question on SO:

> Although you can define multiple quick create forms, only one quick
>   create form can be used by everyone. The form everyone will use is set
>   using the form order. Quick create forms cannot be assigned to
>   security roles and they do not provide the capability for the user to
>   switch forms.

Source: [Quick Create Forms in Dynamics CRM 2013](http://msdynamicscrmblog.wordpress.com/2013/11/01/quick-create-forms-in-dynamics-crm-2013/)

Comment: What a fantastically useless feature!

Comment: I disagree that it is useless. You use the form order to determine which one to use. But the system allows you to _have_ more than one so that you don't get a blocking issue when importing a solution.